# Configuring FreeBSD to get IP from my FreeBSD DHCP Server

Tags: freebsd, dns, dhcp

I have a scenario where I have two `FreeBSD` machines. I setup one to be a `DHCP` server so it can lease IP address. I have provided `IP` ranges, default `DNS` , host name , and all other settings in my `dhcpd.conf` file,

```
option domain-name "josh";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.234.129;

option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.234.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.234.230 192.168.234.235;
  option routers 192.168.234.2;
}
```

and the second one to be a client. When I am running the `FreeBSD` client virtual machine, it has a static `IP` address of `192.168.234.128`, but I want it to lease the IP address from the `FreeBSD DHCP` server that I setup.

I have done this in `rc.d` file,

```
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
```

But how does it know the IP address of the `DHCP` server to lease from?

Both the machines are setup in `VMWare` environment, and are on the same network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client doesn't need to know IP address of the `DHCP` server. Client will send initial packet to all hosts within its subnet using `broadcast` address `255.255.255.255`.
For further reading you may refer to official documentation of `DHCP` protocol
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132
To restart `dhcp` client on particular network interface (`em0`in your case), you may run
`/etc/rc.d/dhclient restart em0`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question 'But how does it know whats the IP address of the DHCP server to lease from ? Can someone please help me with that ?', the answer is whichever DHCP server gets a packet to your machine first.

If you're running in vmware, it would also be running a DHCP server – you'll need to work out how configure it to not provide an address for this vm.